# Change link colour if it contains certain text

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
var test = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i=0; i<test.length; i++) 
if(test[i].innerHTML().indexOf("search string") != -1){test[i].style.color="black";}
```

Hopefully it's obvious what I'm trying to do - if there is a link on the page that contains the search phrase, change it's color to black. This isn't working though. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: SOLVED! meant to be innerHTML, not innerHTML()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`innerHTML` is a property not a function, so don't use `()`.

Answer (score 2):

innerHTML is not a function, it is a property. Try doing this instead:

```
var test = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i=0; i<test.length; i++) 
if(test[i].innerHTML.indexOf("search string") != -1){test[i].style.color="black";}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i=0; i<test.length; i++) {
  var newElem = test[i].innerHTML;
  if(newElem.indexOf("searchString") != -1){
    test[i].style.color="black";
  }
}
```

​innerHTML is no function! It's a property!

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way of doing it would be to use jQuery:

```
var searchTerm = 'term1';

$('a').filter(function (a) {
    if (this.innerHTML.indexOf(searchTerm) != -1)
        return true;
    return false;           
}).css('color','red')
```